# Does javascript pass functions by value or by reference?

Tags: javascript

Javascript passes primitive values by value and objects by value or reference (depends). So how does javascript pass functions around?

```
mercury=()=>{
 console.log("eleven")
}
let eleven = mercury
eleven();
```

so when i pass the function mercury to eleven, is the function passed by value or by reference?

Comment: Functions are objects, just like arrays are objects. (That said, a function's *call behaviour* - i.e. what it does - is immutable, so it doesn't make much difference to being passed by value)

Comment: I saw that answer, but it didn't speak about functions. Only objects and primitive types

Comment: Those links answered the question, but i don't think it is fair to mark it as exact duplicate. :)

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the "exact" bit is part of the canned template and I cannot change it